# C++ Loading information from text file into a 2D Array

Tags: c++, arrays, file, file-io, multidimensional-array

I'm a very novice programmer and I've run into a bit of a problem. I need to load a 2D array with the data stored in a text file. The text file reads as follows (Two numbers then the end of the line. i.e. 1 1949, then next line):

---

1 1949

2 1972

3 1983

4 1959

5 1987

6 1991

7 1995

8 1991

9 1957

10 1980

11 1995

12 1995

---

The array should be formatted in the same fashion. Certainly not looking for an answer here, but a push in the right direction. I've been searching to no avail. Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Are you using static arrays, or are you using C++ vectors?

Comment: This might help your search:  "stackoverflow c++ read file array"

Comment: Can you please explain the file format.  It is not clear to me what matrix is represented by your example input.

Comment: @5gon12eder what I'm understanding is that he has to load the file into a Nx2 matrix and the structure is the same as the input file.

Comment: @user1231958 In this instance I would be using static arrays.

Comment: @user1231958 Maybe, but it would be better if the question did not have us guess.  Also, what is the point of storing a 2D array `int a[n][2]` where `a[i][0] == i + 1` for all `i`?  Or are there maybe “holes” in the file?

Comment: @Astrongitch Do you know about memory allocation in C++?

Comment: This array is being used to display rankings.

Comment: @user1231958 Yeah, I've got a fair grasp on memory allocation.

Comment: I feel that this ain't going anywhere.  @Astrongitch, please edit your question to make it more clear what you need, what you have tried so far and where you need help.  Only then can you expect a useful answer.

Comment: I was doing a bit of research, to refresh my memory on C++, and it happens it's not possible to do this with regular arrays. Are you okay with using vectors instead? This task is really easy with them.

Comment: @user1231958 I certainly wouldn't be opposed to using vectors. I'm just not as familiar with them as I probably should be.

Answer (score 0):

Here I use `pair<int, int>` to store each row; if you have C++11 you can use `array<int, 2>` instead.  The rest is boilerplate, reading and splitting lines.

```
#include <cassert>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  assert(argc == 2);
  ifstream input(argv[1]);
  assert(input);

  vector<pair<int, int> > data;

  for (string line; getline(input, line); )
  {
    istringstream stream(line);
    data.resize(data.size() + 1);
    stream >> data.back().first >> data.back().second;
  }
}
```

Comment: Why not just use `data.push()`?

Comment: @user1231958: you could use `data.push_back()` if you create a temporary `pair` to parse the numbers into.  If you cared a lot about error handling that might even be better.  The way I wrote it may be more efficient though, since no copy is made.

Comment: Just a suggestion, wouldn't it be better to explain the code a bit, given OP is a novice programmer?

Comment: @user1231958: if the OP has specific questions I'll happily answer them.